# Is this $(2n)!\approx (2\pi (2n))^{1/2}((2n)/e)^{2n}$ valid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that $n!\approx (2\pi n)^{1/2}(n/e)^{n}$, but now I have...

$(2n)!\approx (2\pi (2n))^{1/2}((2n)/e)^{2n}$

Is it valid?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it be? It's just a special case of the first one, namely with $n$ even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(2\pi (2n))^{1/2}((2n)/e)^{2n}}$$

Let $u = 2n$. Observe that $u \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

$$ = \lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{(u)!}{(2\pi (u))^{1/2}((u)/e)^{u}}$$

$$ = 1$$